# Read Json schema using Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, databricks

[image: Json data][image: Showing Value as null while reading the schema in databricks]

Showing Value as null while reading the schema

[image: Json data result]

Comment: Why I am getting Value as null while trying to read the json data please resolve this isssue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced your code in my environment. Even i got null value in **value** column.

[image]

So, I figured out these ways to get values in **value** column.

[image]

Code:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([json_data],schema=schema)
display(df)
```

OR

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df_frm_pd = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame([json_data]))
display(df_frm_pd)
```

[image]